# How to select tag inside of a tag using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select `leftcolumn1`. What is the correct approach?

```html
<div class="leftcolumn">
  <div class="card">

    <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">
      <div class="leftcolumn1">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="rField.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rightcolumn1">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="rField.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--<img src="rField.jpg" />-->
    </div>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Explain why the trivial solution `$(".leftcolumn1")` wouldn’t work.

Comment: I suggest reading through [the selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/), which answers this question and many, many others. It doesn't take long at all, and will repay the time you take in saved time later, many times over.

Comment: I am trying to add show and hide "button" for "leftcolumn".

Comment: I am trying to add "show and hide" "button" for "leftcolumn".

Answer (score 1):

To select an *element* within another *element*, you'd use either a [child combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#child-combinators) (if it's an immediate child) or a [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#descendant-combinators) (if it's nested more deeply).

```
// Child combinator (a `>`)
$("selectorForParentElement > selectorForChildElement")

// Descendant combinator (a space)
$("selectorForParentElement selectorForChildElement")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly select this '.leftcolumn1' class.

You can select like this.
`$('.child')`

If you want to select this class which is inside other class,

Then `$('.parent .child')`

If you want select an immediate child.

`$('.parent > .child')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this html() of jquery.
and get elements inside with this

$('.leftcolumn1').html()

Comment: <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#hide").click(function () {
                $(".leftcolumn" , ".leftcolumn1").hide();
            });
            $("#show").click(function () {
                $(".leftcolumn" , ".leftcolumn1").show();
            });
        });
    </script>

Comment: This code is not working  : <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#hide").click(function () {
                $(".leftcolumn" , ".leftcolumn1").hide();
            });
            $("#show").click(function () {
                $(".leftcolumn" , ".leftcolumn1").show();
            });
        });
    </script>

Comment: if you want to get html than you can try this $('.leftcolumn1').html().
what you are going to do, with hide show functions

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice way to do this in jQuery you can specify the 'container' where it should look, like this:

```
$("#selector", "#container");
```

in your case it would be something like this:

`$(".leftcolumn1", ".fakeimg");`

Comment: You have the context concept backwards. The container is second argument

Comment: @charlietfl fixed! Thanks,  I didn't tested the code sorry.